# Is there a way to flatten multiple lists at once

Tags: python, list

Consider the following lists

```
list_1 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
list_2 = [[7,8],[9,10],[11,12]]
list_3 = [[13,14],[15,16],[17,18]]
```

Is it possible to flatten all the lists in one go

i tried using

```
list_1 = [ y for x in list_1 for y in x]
```

this does only one list at a time. Any way to flatten all three lists in a single line of code?

Comment: Why do you want to flatten 3 different lists in one line of code? Why not use 3?

Comment: because i have lot of lists and its repititive

Comment: Throwing everything onto one line is never better than writing multiple lines of code. Perhaps store the lists in another collection and loop over the collection and do the flatten

Comment: Look for a recursive solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists or apply the top voted answer in a loop to each list you have.

Comment: It could be done with `list_1, list_2, list_3 = [[ y for x in list_n for y in x] for list_n in [list_1, list_2, list_3]]` but it's a pretty ridiculous piece of code.

Comment: @cs95 my question is different from the one you have provided. This is not a duplicate question!

Comment: trust me, I've seen this question hundreds of times. Your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40857703/4909087).

Comment: @cs95 The OP has already shown they know how to flatten *a* list; they are asking  how to flatten *multiple* lists at once. The answer you link to doesn't address that.

Comment: @chepner my understanding was that they wanted to "flatten all the lists in one go" meaning flatten it into a single list, although the other, more likely interpretation would've been to call a flatten function over each list in a loop, which they could've easily extended from the duplicate. Another user even posted a comment with the code to do so. I don't think you needed to reopen this.

Comment: @the_reaper What end result do you want? Do you want `list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`, `list_2 = [7,8,9,10,11,12]`, etc, or do you want a single list `list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,...,16,17,18]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be done using `itertools.chain()`

`itertools.chain(list1, list2, list3)`

If you are only worried about lines, then why not this:

```
list1, list2, list3 = ["A","B","C"], [1,2,3], ["E","F","G"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had a *list* of lists to flatten, you could use a loop:

```
list_1 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
list_2 = [[7,8],[9,10],[11,12]]
list_3 = [[13,14],[15,16],[17,18]]

lists = [list_1, list_2, list_3]

def flatten(lst):
    ...

lists = [flatten(lst) for lst in lists]
```

Your problem is that you are trying to generalize something that can't be generalized: a set of independent variables. Ignoring unrecommended solutions involving dynamic variable names corrections, what you should do is simply enumerate the flattened lists:

```
list_1 = flatten(list_1)
list_2 = flatten(list_2)
list_3 = flatten(list_3)
```

Comment: "Your problem is that you are trying to generalize something that can't be generalized" Why not? As long as they have a manageable number of lists, `list_1, list_2, list_3 = [flatten(lst) for lst in [list_1, list_2, list_3]]` would be sufficient.

Comment: "because i have lot of lists and its repititive". I suspect there are far more than 3 lists in the OP's actual code.